# Undefined reference to wxGLCanvas' constructor?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, deprecated, undefined-reference

I used `wx-config --libs` to generate the linker arguments for my application, and the output is the following:

`-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0`

My application compiles but does not link, instead citing an undefined reference to the constructor for a wxGLCanvas. I know one constructor is deprecated, but I appear to be using the one that isn't: `wxGLCanvas(<frame>,wxID_ANY,NULL)` as seen in http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_g_l_canvas.html.

The remainder of the linker errors are all undefined references to various methods of wxGLCanvas. For safe measure, I added `-DwxUSE_GLCANVAS=1` to all targets, but this had no effect. What am I doing wrong?

In case it's relevant, I also use `wx-config --cflags` during compilation:

`-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread`

Notice also that the documents still recommend using SetCurrent, which appears to be marked deprecated. Are there more recent documents than the ones I linked?

Comment: *Where* do you put the libraries to be linked with? I mean on the command-line? The order of object files and libraries may be important. Always put libraries *after* your object (or source) files.

Comment: At the end of the line:

`$(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)`

...where LDFLAGS is...

`LDFLAGS:=$(LDFLAGS) $$(wx-config --libs) -lGL`

As an aside, the application linked when it was just a window without a wxGLCanvas.

Comment: [Reading this wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxGLCanvas) it seems that you need to add `--gl-libs` to the `wx-config` command to get the OpenGL libraries. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you have 2 versions of `wxWidgets` installed you may have 2 versions of the config tool. On my system I have to use `wx-config-3.0` rather than `wx-config` if I am using `v3` headers.

Comment: That did it Joachim, thank you! 
@Galik I don't appear to have wx-config-3.0 despite installing 3.0 dev.

Answer (score 1):

`wx-config --libs` is equivalent to `wx-config --libs std` where "std" stands for the subset of "standard" libraries which are considered to be used by default. If you want to use any of the libraries not in this list, such as "webview", "richtext" or indeed "gl", you need to list them explicitly.

So the correct command to use in your case is `wx-config --libs std,gl`.